# Image upload for each product color

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mern, multer

I currently have a small problem to ensure that each color added has the associated image, I specify the code returns me what I want on the React side but on the Nodejs side the images uploader for an image is attributed to all my colors , I show you the code

Here is my react code :

```
const colorData = colors.map((color) => ({
    name: color.name,
        images: color.images.map((image) => {
          const uploadedImage = image.fileToSend;
          if (uploadedImage) {
            formData.append(`images`, uploadedImage);
            return uploadedImage;
          }
          return null;
        }),
      }));

      formData.append("colors", JSON.stringify(colorData));

      console.log("colordata from front:", colorData)
```

this code returns me the data that I want

server side function :

```
const createProduct = async (req, res) => {
  const { name, description, price, stock, categoryId, colors } = req.body;
  const uploadedImages = req.files;

  try {
    const validateField = (fieldName) => {
      if (!req.body[fieldName]) {
        return res.json({ error: `Le champ ${fieldName} est obligatoire` });
      }
    };

    validateField("name");
    validateField("price");
    validateField("stock");
    validateField("categoryId");

    if (req.fileFilterError) {
      return res.json({ error: req.fileFilterError });
    }

    // Check if slug exist
    const exist = await Product.findOne({ slug: slugify(name) });
    if (exist) {
      return res.json({
        error: "Veuillez fournir un nom de produit différent.",
      });
    }

    const colorData = JSON.parse(colors).map((color) => ({
      name: color.name,
      images: color.images.map((image, index) => {
        const uploadedImage = req.files[index];
        if (uploadedImage) {
          return req.protocol + "://" + req.get("host") + "/uploads/" + uploadedImage.filename;
        }
        return null;
      }),
    }));

    console.log("Color from back:", colorData);
    const product = await Product.create({
      name,
      description,
      price: parseFloat(price.replace(",", ".")),
      stock,
      colors: colorData,
      category: categoryId,
      slug: slugify(name),
    });

    res.json({ product, success: "Produit créé avec succès !" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error in createProduct", error);
  }
};
```

you can see what the console log returns to me in this function :

```
Color from back: [
  {
    name: 'Jaune',
    images: [
      'http://localhost:3000/uploads/38933fe5-ae8e-48fb-bf30-db791894d2cc-jaune.jpeg',
      'http://localhost:3000/uploads/0842af0d-62ba-4e81-be65-64beeefa6933-jaune2.jpeg'
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Violet',
    images: [
      'http://localhost:3000/uploads/38933fe5-ae8e-48fb-bf30-db791894d2cc-jaune.jpeg',
      'http://localhost:3000/uploads/0842af0d-62ba-4e81-be65-64beeefa6933-jaune2.jpeg'
    ]
  }
]
```

I think you have understood what I expected as an answer I hope you could help me knowing that I use Multer for image upload and that in my route I have determined my upload fields like this :

```
router.post("/", isAdmin, upload.array("images"), createProduct);
```

Hoping that one of you can guide me, thank you in advance!

Comment: Does anyone have a solution?